# UnicodeDecodeError -Decoding and saving in Excel

Tags: python, excel, unicode, decode, encode

I'm trying to save some data I scraped in an excel sheet, and I'm having unicode decode problems with one particular piece, that has the following form:

```
work_info['title'] = Darimān-i afsaradgī : rāhnamā-yi kāmil bira-yi hamah-ʼi khānvādahʹhā
```

The code that is causing the error is:

```
data.write(b + book + accumulated_books+ 2, 43, work_info['title'])
wb.save('/Users/apple/Downloads/WC Scrape_trialfortwo.csv')
```

And the error is:

> > UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)

I've tried several different encoding/decoding techniques, but nothing have worked so far. Any suggestion would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the error occur on the `data.write` line or `wb.save`? What Excel/Python library are you using? Do you really want a CSV or XLS[X] file?

Comment: @NickT When I leave everything as it is, the error is in wb.save. When I try encoding, the error is in data.write. I'm using xlrd, and saving everything in a CSV file.

Comment: xlwt? xlrd is for reading I thought...and I don't think it will emit a CSV, but XLS **only**. The Unicode examples seem pretty straightfoward; I'm guessing it assumes UTF-8, so you don't have to do hardly anything: https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/blob/master/examples/unicode1.py

Comment: @NickT Yes, it is, but I'm using xutils to copy xlrd.Book objects into xlwt.Workbook objects so they can be manipulated. With that I can modify cells and then save the changed workbook back to a file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using python2, and python2's unicode/bytes handling is causing the problem.

```
>>> s = 'Darimān-i afsaradgī : rāhnamā-yi kāmil bira-yi hamah-ʼi khānvādahʹhā'
>>> wb = Workbook()
>>> ws = wb.add_sheet('test')
>>> ws.write(1, 0, s)
>>> wb.save('test.xls')
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

`xlwt` assumes that `s` is an ascii-encoded string and tries to decode it to unicode, but fails:

```
>>> s.decode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

In fact, `s` is encoded as utf-8:

```
>>> s.decode('utf-8') 
u'Darim\u0101n-i afsaradg\u012b : r\u0101hnam\u0101-yi k\u0101mil bira-yi hamah-\u02bci kh\u0101nv\u0101dah\u02b9h\u0101'
```

The simplest solution may be to encode your workbook as utf-8:

```
>>> wb = Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
>>> ws = wb.add_sheet('test')
>>> ws.write(1, 0, s)
>>> wb.save('test.xls')
```

If you need a finer-grained approach, you could explicitly decode the string to unicode before writing it to the worksheet:

```
>>> wb = Workbook()
>>> ws = wb.add_sheet('test')
>>> ws.write(1, 0, s.decode('utf-8'))
>>> wb.save('test.xls')
```